Square Roots of Non-Negative Even Functions
I'm trying to study properties of maps between quotients of representations of compact Lie groups and I stumbled upon the following problem. Suppose you have a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with the following properties.

$f(0)=0$ and $f(x)>0$ for all $x\neq 0$
$f(x)$ is even (i.e. $f(-x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$)

Question: Does $f(x)$ admit a smooth square root?
If there exists a minimal $n$ so that $f^{(2n)}(0)\neq 0$, then it's easy to show that yes, the square root is smooth. Because then
$$g(x):=\frac{f(x)}{x^{2n}}$$
is a strictly positive smooth function and so $\sqrt{g(x)}$ is smooth and thus so is $h(x)=\sqrt{g(x)}x^n$ which squares to $f(x)$.
The part I'm getting stuck on is the case where $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n$. Clearly this isn't a problem for functions like $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$, but I'm not sure if anything can be generalized from this example. I looked at previous mathoverflow posts and the accompanying listed papers( e.g. Square root of a positive $C^\infty$ function.) but the counterexamples listed do not satisfy my hypotheses.
Perhaps someone here with a stronger background in analysis than me knows where I could look?

The example by Evan Jenkins from that post seem to almost work, you just have to extend it to an even function for $x < 0$ instead of $0$.

That's a really good idea, don't know why I didn't think of that. A little frustrating that there's no proof in the paper, but I'll try and think of something. Thanks!
